# Vite Vue 3 Capacitor "Unexpected token {" error on older android device

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js, capacitor, vite

### I'm working on a cross-platform application using vue 3 + vite and ionic capacitor 3. There was a problem when testing on an old device (didn't appear when testing on a newer device; the problem may be in webview version).

---

A problem occurred on the device:

**Android 6.0.1 |
WebView 64.0.3282.137**

*Errors from debug*:

```
E/Capacitor: JavaScript Error: {"type":"js.error","error":{"message":"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {","url":"http://localhost/assets/index.e1b49e1f.js","line":1,"col":53918,"errorObject":"{}"}}
E/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/ - Line 287 - Msg: SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
E/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/assets/index.e1b49e1f.js - Line 1 - Msg: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

*Problematic piece of code from **index.e1b49e1f.js*** :

```
{try{e[n]=0}catch{}e.removeAttribute(n);return}}
```

It says that something is wrong with `{` right after the `catch`

---

Answer (score 0):

Android Webview is too old

```js
try {

} catch {}
```

Let's replace it with a new method:

```js
try {

} catch (e) {}
```